# Create custom command in tmux

Tags: tmux

I know how to bind a key to a command in tmux, but I want to create a custom command (that you can type with prefix key + colon). In this custom command, I want to execute a couple of other commands.

My idea is to have something like this:

```
no-side-status() {
    set status-left-length 0
    set status-right-length 0
}

side-status() {
    set status-left-length 50
    set status-right-length 150
}
```

So I can type `:no-side-status` to hide the left and right status bars, and type `:side-status` to restore the left and right status bars.

Is it possible to create such custom commands? If so how? If not, any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: You can have your own bash functions if you like. Not sure about which status bars are you talking about.

Comment: @MinusFour The tmux status bars..

Comment: Try adding the function keyword to your functions and add them at the bottom of your ~/.bashrc. Then execute them like no-side-status() from your tmux session.

Comment: @MinusFour I understand I can make a bash function and talk to tmux through the `tmux` command, but I would like to make a tmux function that I can execute by typing `prefix-key + :` and then the command name. Because if I'm in a vim session or something, I don't want to have to go back to bash to execute this command.

Comment: When you are in Vim you can execute the same command with !. For example :!no-side-status(). If you are looking for the same command from Vim and Bash, then I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 7):

Originally, tmux doesn't have any support for custom commands except for running external shell scripts.

There's a mod adding full-fledged scripting support to tmux: http://ershov.github.io/tmux/

It also allows to create user commands. For example, yours would look like:

```
proc no-side-status {} {
    set status-left-length 0
    set status-right-length 0
}

proc side-status {} {
    set status-left-length 50
    set status-right-length 150
}
```

To use from tmux command line just type `C-b :` and `side-status` or `no-side-status`.

To bind it to a key use `bind C-p tcl side-status`.

Comment: does https://github.com/ershov/tmux support current tmux 3.3a release?

Answer (score 4):

`bind C-p run "/usr/bin/notify-send Foo"`

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: Partial answering, that you can bind shortcut to a external shell function. 
(that you can type with prefix key + colon)

Comment: I'm not trying to bind an external shell function to a shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

This is the full answer. You can have two tmux configuration.
One contain

```
set status-left-length 0
set status-right-length 0
bind-key R source-file ~/.tmux.alternative.conf \; \
                    display-message "Alternative configuration loaded"
```

The other contain

```
set status-left-length 50
set status-right-length 15
bind-key R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; \
                    display-message "Default configuration loaded"
```

Comment: I could try this approach, though I actually don't want to bind it to a keyboard shortcut but want to create a custom command.

Comment: Good luck. It seems difficult without hacking the tmux core. You should consider the answers above, binding a key to shell scripts/functions.

Answer (score 2):

The closest experience you can get right now is:

1. create tmux shell script and put it in $PATH
2. run the script inside tmux using the `run-shell` command (short: `ru`)

Example in tmux (say the script is named `tm.xx`)

```
c-b :ru tm.xx
```

So you are typing three extra characters - `ru`

Comment: Agreed that this is probably the best bet still almost 7 years after the question was asked.  I was thinking `:source tm.tmux` for "pure tmux commands", but that can't handle the PATH.  `run-shell` can.

Answer (score 0):

tmux supports float windows now. You could popup a window by using `tmux display-popup`. And then in this popup window, run the script you want to use.

Comment: Could you please use full sentences and correct your grammar? Even with knowledge about the topic it is hard to grasp what you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

Define a command alias by adding something like this to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -s command-alias[10] widevim='splitw -bvfp 80 "vim -O2"'
```